# Адаптивное наложение картинки на картинку - как?

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap

Как например эту картинку накладывать при наведении на те что в галерее ?

Что-бы была адаптивной и не вылезала на других размерах экрана.

Вот картинка которую нужно наложить , она одного размера с остальными:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#kartinki img {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section id="kartinki">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/one_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/azbuka/n2c.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/tri_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/four_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/five_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/six_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/seven_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/eight_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/azbuka/n9c.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/number_10_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/number_11_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/number_12_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно реализовать так:

```css
#kartinki a {
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

#kartinki a:hover:after {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGHje.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section id="kartinki">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/one_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/azbuka/n2c.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/tri_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/four_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/five_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/six_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/seven_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/eight_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/azbuka/n9c.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/number_10_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/number_11_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.raskraska.ru/zifra_digital/img/number_12_orange.gif"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```